# jQuery double click, but don't select the content

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery's dbclick() function in order to toggle highlight of the table raw. The problem I'm facing is that whenever I double click the content of the cell is also selected. Is there an easy way to prevent content selection?

My code:

```
if ($('.tbl_repeat').length > 0) {
    $('.tbl_repeat tr').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('tr_active');
    });
}
```

Perhaps I didn't make myself clear - I don't want to disable selecting all together - only when the double click occurs - apart from this event everything else should be selectable as usual.

Comment: @shaheer, I don't think that will work in this case. The default behavior of the text is not the fact it is selected, it doesn't have one. your example would work on things like links and submit buttons.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to deny selection via css on element what you doubleclick

```
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select     : none;
   -khtml-user-select   : none;
   -webkit-user-select  : none;
   -o-user-select       : none;
   user-select          : none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Place the below coding between  here  (between Head Tags)

```
<style>
        .unselectable {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;   
        }
    </style>
```

Put this in between  here  (between Body Tags)

```
<p class="unselectable"> your unselectable text here </p>
```

Just like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .unselectable {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;   
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="unselectable">
    <span> your unselectable text here </span><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;"> your unselectable link here </a></p>
</body>
</html>​
```